# Groovy script to get Jenkins trigger time

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to get the trigger time of all jobs in Jenkins so that I can decide on when to schedule it.
Following script displays an object, but is unable to get the schedule time and date.

```
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.*;
import jenkins.plugins.slack.*;
jobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getAllItems(FreeStyleProject)
for (job in jobs) {
           timeT=job.triggers();
           println "job: " + job.getFullName() + " " + timeT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, however this works (small adoption from https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+timer+triggers)

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  if(item.disabled || item instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) {
    continue; 
  }
    for(trigger in item.triggers.values()) {
        if(trigger instanceof TimerTrigger) {
            println("--- Timer trigger for " + item.name + " ---")
            println(trigger.spec + '\n')
        }
    }
}
```

Creates this output:

```
--- Timer trigger for XXX ---
30 4 * * 1-5

--- Timer trigger for YYY ---
0 6 * * 1-5
```

And an even more complex script (with some minor adoptions from same source)

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*

class Timer {
  String name;
  String spec;
  int minute;
  int hour;

  Timer(pname,pspec) {
    name=pname;
    spec=pspec;
    def parts=pspec.split(" ")
    minute=parts[0].toInteger()
    hour=parts[1].toInteger()
  }
}

def timers = []

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  if(item instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) {
    continue; 
  }
  for(trigger in item.triggers.values()) {
    if(trigger instanceof TimerTrigger) {
      try {
      def timer=new Timer(item.name,trigger.spec)
      timers.add(timer)
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        println(trigger.spec + " " + item.name)
      }
    }
  }
}

timers.sort{a,b -> a.hour <=> b.hour ?: a.minute <=> b.minute}
for (timer in timers) {
  printf("%02d:%02d %s\n",timer.hour,timer.minute,timer.name)
}
```

Creates:

```
  00:30 MyFixedScheduledJob
  @midnight MyAroundMidnightJob
  H 06 * * 1-5 MyJobWithHash
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18473946)

Comment: @Pedram Thank you for pointing this out - I've changed it now properly as you suggested.